# Dynamically generate function arguments python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, closures

I am working in Python 2.7 and need to generate a list of functions each of which has a different default argument but where the functions are explained. This is not the best explanation, but I think the example below clarifies my question. Is there a way of doing this?

```
function_list = []
for i in range(10):
    function_list.append(lambda x: myfunc(i,x))

def myfunc(a,b):
    print a + b
```

This doesn't work, as, in this example, all functions in the function list return 9 + x

In the example above "x" is a separate variable to be passed to the function in a different way.

I realise that this is a pretty ugly construction but have inherited a large amount of code around this that would need to be changed to avoid this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `i` as a default value for a lambda with two arguments. This way it will fit better to the question description:

> need to generate a list of functions each of which has a different default argument

for the following code:

```
function_list = []
for i in range(10):
    function_list.append(lambda x, y=i: myfunc(x,y))

for f in function_list:
    f(5)
```

The output will be:

```
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

also you can use `f` with two arguments:

```
for j,f in enumerate(function_list):
    f(j+2,5)
```

and you'll get:

```
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
```